# AutoHotKey Key Switching

Tags: autohotkey

Hey i'm trying to create a ahk script that will allow me to press one key "q" and have it toggle the "e" key to send either "o" or "p" depending on the variable "count". I have it working somewhat, the only problem is that I can't get the "q" key to work. When i press "q" nothing shows up although the "e" key does switch like I want it to.

```
count = 1

q::
If (count = 1) {
    count = 2
    MsgBox Count is set to 2
    return
} else if (count = 2) {
    count = 1
    MsgBox Count is set to 1
    return
}

e::
If (count = 1) {
    Send o
    return
}
If (count = 2) {
    Send p
    return
}


Escape::
ExitApp
Return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch between two different options for something by pressing a key or a key combination, toggle a variable's value between true(1) and false(0) using the := operator

```
toggle := 1 ; true (Option 1)
MsgBox Option 1: "e" to "o"

$q::     ; $ prevents the key from triggering itself
toggle := !toggle
If (toggle)
    MsgBox Option 1: "e" to "o"
else
    MsgBox Option 2: "e" to "p"
return

$e::
If (toggle)
    Send o
else
    Send p
return
```

To increase a variable's value, use the ++ operator:

```
count = 0

$q::
count++
If (count = 1)
    MsgBox Count is set to 1
else 
If (count = 2)
     MsgBox Count is set to 2
else {
    count = 1 ; reset
    MsgBox Count is set to 1
}
return

$e::
If (count = 1)
    Send o
If (count = 2)
    Send p
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Operators